# What's the strong point to take into consideration to choose between .NET or Java generator in GeneXus KBs?

Tags: genexus

GeneXus allows you to generate your KB in Java and/or .NET. I was searching several days, without success if exists some strong reason to choose one of both or if it's just a personal preference.

I guess is more related to interact with Java/.NET libraries, but I'm not sure, and can't find samples about this decission. BTW Some GeneXus.com subsites (wiki, training..) are in. NET and others in Java.

And this is my main question. There are some point/important difference, technical decission (performance? deploying? ...) and so on to take into consideration to choose between Java or .NET as generator for your project, or is mainly related to a personal preference to work with "Tomcat" or IIS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the time, you end up using the generator that best suites the customer's technology stack, so there's no much decision to make. However, if the decision is completely up to you, I think currently one strong argument is **money**.

If you go for `Java` you can deploy your application to a free platform, for example, `Linux` + `Apache Tomcat` + `MariaDB`. Because of this, if you deploy to a `PaaS` or `IaaS`, you will get lower prices, than `.Net`.

This is about to change, however, because the next version of `GeneXus` (code-named `GeneXus Tero`) will introduce a new generator for `.Net Core` applications, that will enable developers to deploy their applications to free platforms too.

As of performance, reliability and scalability, both generators (and platforms) are quite mature and have many years in the market, so there's no much difference.

Other than that, I cannot find other arguments to choose one or the other, beyond personal preferences or the experience of the development team on each platform.